# Header Issues on Webpage

Tags: html, css

I am creating a website and am having some header/navigation problems. I have centered the website (works fine) and my header begins where it should on the page but when I add a border-bottom to the header it starts where it should but continues to right side of the page. Also my nav bar (which is a float: right) begins on the right-most side of the webpage. HTML and CSS to follow. I know it is probably obvious but I am at a loss.

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html {
  background-color: #FFF;
  max-width: 100%;
}

body {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 1024px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
  font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
}

header {
  height: 6em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #00529C;
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100% !important;
  z-index: 1;
}

nav {
  max-width: 50%;
}

.hdrmenu ul {
  margin-right: 1em;
  padding-top: 1.5em;
}

.hdrmenu li {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  /*margin: auto;*/
}

.hdrmenu li a {
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0em 2em;
  /*list-style: none;*/
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #00529C;
}
```

```html
<header class="bg transition">
  <nav class="hdrmenu">
    <a href="index.html"><img src="_images/1280_AcYxdW7KNtA0.png" class="logo"></a>
    <ul style="float: right;">
      <li><a href="ardvark.html" class="slide-left-right">Ardvark</a></li>
      <li><a href="beaver.html" class="slide-left-right">Beaver</a></li>
      <li><a href="cougar.html" class="slide-left-right">Cougar</a></li>
      <li><a href="dinosaur.html" class="slide-left-right">Dinosaur</a></li>
      <li><a href="elephant.html" class="slide-left-right">Elephant</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>

<section class="mainContent">
  <h1>Animals</h1>
  <p>Blah, Blah</p>
</section>
```

Comment: It's hard to know exactly what you are trying to achieve. Do you want the header (and border bottom) to stretch the whole width of the screen? And I presume the <section> to be displayed below the header?

Comment: Does this achieve what you want? https://repl.it/@rhodespeter2/Header-issue

Answer (score 0):

Here you have:

```
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
  font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
}

header, 
.mainContent {
  width: 1024px;
}

.mainContent {
  margin: 120px auto 0;
}

header {
  height: 6em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #00529C;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  margin: 0 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.hdrmenu ul {
  margin-right: 1em;
  padding-top: 1.5em;
}

.hdrmenu li {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
}

.hdrmenu li a {
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0em 2em;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #00529C;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix your border, you'll want to ensure that your `<header>` element doesn't take up too much space. The problem is that it has `position: fixed`, so `width` will apply relative to its current `position`. I assume you'll want it to be two-thirds of the page, centralised. This can be achieved by simply subtracting the right-hand space from the element (with `width: calc(100% / 3 * 2)`). And don't set an `!important` rule for this like you had in your example; `!important` is generally considered bad practice. You should read up on [specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/) instead.

You'll also want to remove your rules set on `<html>` and `<body>` and make use of a class called `.container` or something similar. These are document tags, and shouldn't really have positioning rules applied. Once the rules have been shifted to `.container`, instead of using a hard-coded `width: 1024px`, use **`max-width`** to allow the element to shrink when necessary.

Then, if you want your navbar's links to `float` to the `right`, you'll want to remove `max-width: 50%` from `nav`.

This can be seen in the following:

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-width: calc(100% / 3 * 2);
  background-color: #FFF;
  font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
  font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
}

header {
  height: 6em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #00529C;
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: calc(100% / 3 * 2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.hdrmenu ul {
  margin-right: 1em;
  padding-top: 1.5em;
}

.hdrmenu li {
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
  /*margin: auto;*/
}

.hdrmenu li a {
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0em 2em;
  /*list-style: none;*/
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #00529C;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <header class="bg transition">
    <nav class="hdrmenu">
      <a href="index.html"><img src="_images/1280_AcYxdW7KNtA0.png" class="logo"></a>
      <ul style="float: right;">
        <li><a href="ardvark.html" class="slide-left-right">Ardvark</a></li>
        <li><a href="beaver.html" class="slide-left-right">Beaver</a></li>
        <li><a href="cougar.html" class="slide-left-right">Cougar</a></li>
        <li><a href="dinosaur.html" class="slide-left-right">Dinosaur</a></li>
        <li><a href="elephant.html" class="slide-left-right">Elephant</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <section class="mainContent">
    <h1>Animals</h1>
    <p>Blah, Blah</p>
  </section>
</div>
```

Note that you may also want a [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) to swap to a 'wider' view on mobile.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the snippet here if that's what you want

https://jsfiddle.net/qu9hg84o/7/

As @obsidian-age says, the problem is `position: fixed`. `position:fixed` will take the content out of normal flow, so body can't contain header and hence the border flows till end. Because, for `position: fixed`, container will be `viewport`. Check [position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) and [containing_block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Containing_block) about position and containing blocks.

Also, you might want to remove `width: 50%` on nav, it positions nav items awkwardly somewhere in middle on the page.

And, removing `float: left` on list items `li` will stack up the list items on your right if that's also what you are expecting.